# Powershell ISE AzureAD Trouble output Select Properties to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, azure-active-directory, export-to-csv

I am trying to setup code to output a list in csv of peoples Name, Job Title, Manger's Name and Manger's E-mail.  How ever when I try to output to the CSV I get a numbers rather then what I see at the console output.

```
Connect-AzureAD
$Tester = 'Me@MyCorp.com'
$User = @()
$UserJob =@()
$Manger = @()
$UserDetails  = @()
$Output = @()
Write-Host 'New Result'
$User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $Tester |Select-Object DisplayName
$UserJob = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $Tester |Select-Object JobTitle
$Manger = Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $Tester |Select-Object DisplayName, Mail
Write-Host $User
Write-Host $Manger

$Result = ($Tester, $User, $UserJob, $Manger)
Write-Host 'Final'
$Result| Export-Csv -Path "C:\UserExisting\NewResult.csv"
Disconnect-AzureAD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Connect-AzureAD
$Tester = 'userprincipalname@mycompany.com'
$User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $Tester | Select-Object DisplayName,JobTitle
$Manager = $Manger = Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $Tester | Select-Object DisplayName, Mail
$Result = [pscustomobject] @{DisplayName=$user.DisplayName; JobTitle=$user.JobTitle; Manager="$($Manager.DisplayName) <$($Manager.Mail)>"}

$Result | Format-List

$Result | Export-Csv -Path "C:\UserExisting\NewResult.csv" -NoTypeInformation
Disconnect-AzureAD
```

I recommend creating a pscustomobject with the desired attributes. PSCustomObjects are designed for Export-Csv